# Unresposive div when resizing web page

Tags: html, css

I want the input with class `searchbox` to get smaller when it gets close to the link `#hamburder`

HTML code:

```
    <div class="site-wrapper">
        <div class="header-wrapper">
            <div class="hamburger-menu">

            </div>
            <div class="header-wrapper-links">
                <ul>
                    <li class="header-wrapper-li">
                        <a class="header-wrapper-button"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="header-wrapper-li">
                        <div id="hamburger-button">
                            <a id="hamburger"></a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <section class="header-content">
                <input class="searchbox" type="text" placeholder="Search without being tracked">
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS code:

```
.site-wrapper {
    max-width: 85rem;
    padding: 0 4.3rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.header-wrapper {
    padding: 1rem 0;
}
.header-wrapper-links {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    padding: 10px auto;
    margin: 30px auto 0 auto;
}
.header-wrapper-links ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

#hamburger-button {
    position: relative;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    transition: ease-in-out 100ms;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#hamburger-button:hover {
    background-color: #c6c6c680;
}
#hamburger {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-image: url(/assets/menuicon.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;   
    padding: 9.2px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.header-content {
    max-width: 620px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.searchbox {
    width: 100%;
    height: 2.5rem;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #c6c6c680;
    font-size: 11.2pt;
    padding: 0 1.2rem;
}
.searchbox:focus {
    outline: none;
}
.searchbox:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #aeaeae80;
}
.searchbox:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #aeaeae80;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code to manage your style depending the size of the window.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
}
```

Media query doc : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp